# T-SQL query - aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2016. I have the following sample data:

```
    Date      Total_Req.    Changed     Deleted     New
    9/16/2008   271            7          1          3
    10/14/2008  235            1         10         11
    10/15/2008  131            2          3          5
    11/21/2009  190            4          5          2
    11/22/2009  125            5         12          1
    11/23/2009  181            6          1          4
    4/13/2011   300            8          2          8
    4/26/2011   281            11         7          9
    4/26/2011   302             5         8         10
```

I can easily to aggregate per month using something like:

```
    Select cast(Format([Date], 'MM/01/yyyy') as date) as [Date], 
    SUM([Changed]) as [Changed], SUM([Deleted]) as [Deleted], SUM([New]) as 
    [New] GRPUP BY Format([Date], 'MM/01/yyyy')
```

So far so good, I get a sum by month:

```
    Date        Changed Deleted New
    9/1/2008    7          1    3
    10/1/2008   3         13    16
    11/1/2009   15        18    7
    4/1/2011    19         9    17
```

However, I need to include in the query the value of *Total_Req for the **last date in a month***, so desired output would be:

```
    Date    Total Req.  Changed Deleted New
    9/1/2008    271        7     1      3
    10/1/2008   131        3     13    16
    11/1/2009   181       15    18      7
    4/1/2011    302       19    9      17
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks,
M.R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run a subquery back to the original table from the SELECT clause back to the original table:

```
SELECT cast(Format([Date], 'MM/01/yyyy') as date) as [Date],
    (SELECT TOP 1 [Total_Req.] FROM [MyTable] t0 WHERE Format(t0.[Date], 'MM/01/yyyy') = Format(t.[Date], 'MM/01/yyyy') ORDER BY t0.[Date] DESC) as [Total_Req.],
    SUM([Changed]) as [Changed], SUM([Deleted]) as [Deleted], SUM([New]) as [New] 
FROM [MyTable] t
GROUP BY Format([Date], 'MM/01/yyyy')
```

or

```
SELECT cast(Format([Date], 'MM/01/yyyy') as date) as [Date],
    MIN(t1.[Total_Req.]) As [Total_Req.],
    SUM([Changed]) as [Changed], SUM([Deleted]) as [Deleted], SUM([New]) as [New] 
FROM [MyTable] t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 [Total_Req.] FROM [MyTable] t0 WHERE Format(t0.[Date], 'MM/01/yyyy') = Format(t.[Date], 'MM/01/yyyy') ORDER BY t0.[Date] DESC) t1
GROUP BY Format([Date], 'MM/01/yyyy')
```

If you really need faster results, take a look at the `FORMAT([Date], 'MM/01/yyyy')` expression. This expression cuts to the core of this query, as it's used in three different ways, including the matching condition for the subquery or APPLY. The expression is also **not sargeable**, meaning no matter what indexes you have they won't help you with query elements that need this value.

If you add a **computed column** to the table for this expression, you can then use the new column in an index and you should get **much** faster results.

Comment: Thanks Joel, it works but for a table with 55,000 records is not very efficient....

Comment: 55,000 records is peanuts. I had a version with CROSS APPLY, too, but I don't know if that would be any faster.

Comment: If you just put a separate index on each column, that's not how indexes work and won't help you.

Comment: Added composite indexes, still slow.

Comment: Added the APPLY option you can try, but not really expecting it to be faster. Sometimes you get surprised, though, and I'd honestly expect this to be slower because it's gonna produce an interim result for every record and then do an aggregate of that for each group, rather than just finding the result once for each group at the end.

Comment: Also added a note about using a computed column to pre-compute the MONTH value, which should make things **MUCH** faster.

Comment: I followed your advice and created a computed column + index and this solved the performance issue. takes 1 sec compared to 36 sec before the change ! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a correlated subquery for the Total Req column, selecting the total Req where the date is the MAX(date) for the month of the row in the outer query.   (or use TOP 1 Order by date DESC in the subquery).